# Pass ajax data from Controller to directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Hey I have build some kind of datepicker + modal pop up window.
I want the system to operate in the following manner, the user pick 2 dates: start date and end date, this defines the range. Then the user click the GO button, the Go button then operate some kind of ajax call to the server and retrieve data which need to be presented.
The Go button is part of the directive template, now I have a couple of questions:

1. Where should I do the ajax call? inside the directive or in the controller?
2. If I am doing the ajax call inside the controller, how should I pass the data quick enough so when I click the GO button then I will see the data in the opening popup modal?
3. what are my choices for passing ajax data from controller to a directive?

[image]

I am attaching the following directive code, please look at the collection variable as the variable which need to contain the ajax data which need to be preseted.

```
angular.module('directives', [])
    .directive('datepicker', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        // Runs during compile
        return {
            scope: {
                id: '@',
                "class": '@',
                onSelect: "&",
                onSelectStartDate: '&',
                onSelectEndDate: '&',
                onSelectGoMode: '&',
                collection: '=' // ajax data
            },
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div id="{{id}}" class="{{class}}">' +
                    '<div id="date-start-wrapper" class="date-wrapper">' +
                        '<label for="datepicker-start" class="datepicker-lbl">From:</label>' +
                        '<div class="fieldWrapper">' +
                            '<input id="datepicker-start" type="date"  placeholder="Select date" />' +
                            '<a class="calendar"></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div id="date-end-wrapper" class="date-wrapper">' +
                        '<label for="datepicker-end" class="datepicker-lbl">To:</label>' +
                        '<div class="fieldWrapper">' +
                            '<input id="datepicker-end" type="date" placeholder="Select date" />' +
                            '<a class="calendar"></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<button id="GoBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" >GO</button>' +
                    '<div id="blackout"></div>'+
                        '<div id="popup">'+
                            '<span class="close"></span>' +
                            '<h2>Enter Content</h2>' +
                            '<span>{{collection}}</span>'+
                            '<button id="okbtn" class="btn btn-success btn-md" >ok</button>' +
                            '<button id="cancelbtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-md" >cancel</button>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>'
                        ,
            replace: true,
            link: function ($scope, iElm, iAttrs, controller) {
                console.log('directive iAttrs', iAttrs);
                var Gobtn = iElm.find('button');
                $scope.selectStartDate = function (time) {
                    if (angular.isFunction($scope.onSelectStartDate())) {
                        $scope.onSelectStartDate()(time);
                    }
                }
                $scope.selectEndDate = function (time) {
                    if (angular.isFunction($scope.onSelectEndDate())) {
                        $scope.onSelectEndDate()(time);
                    }
                }
                //define blackout and close click callbacks.
                $("#blackout, .close").click(function () {
                    $("#blackout").removeClass("visable");
                    $("#popup").removeClass("visable");
                });

                Gobtn.click(function () {
                    console.log('$scope.onSelectGoMode()', $scope.onSelectGoMode());
                    if (angular.isFunction($scope.onSelectGoMode())) {
                        $scope.onSelectGoMode()();
                    }
                    $("#blackout").addClass("visable");
                    $("#popup").addClass("visable");
                });

                var actions = [$scope.selectStartDate, $scope.selectEndDate];
                $(".date-wrapper").each(function (index) {
                    console.log('directive index', index);
                    console.log('actions:', actions);
                    $input = $(this).find('input');
                    $btn = $(this).find('.calendar');

                    console.log('input', $input[0]);
                    console.log('btn', $btn[0]);
                    var counter = 0;
                    var updateTime = $scope.selectDate;

                    $input.attr('type', 'text');
                    var pickerStart = new Pikaday({
                        field: $input[0],
                        trigger: $btn[0],
                        container: $(this)[0],
                        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
                        firstDay: 1,
                        onSelect: actions[index]
                    });
                    $btn.show();
                    counter++;
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Since you are using a directive and all you data is redily availble in directives scope you make a api call there itself and also use modal service inside directive to make it popup on the current view.

Comment: the problem is that after I click the GO btn, I will operate the ajax call in the directive but wheh I click OK for the popup window modal, I need to operate another ajax call which should update the entire screen ,which his data is inside the controller.

Comment: use $emit or $broadcast event...
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an independent functioning date picker and range selector along with a action button,you can go ahead and make an ajax call inside the directive function . As you directive will create a new scope for your template and all you data will be readily available inside that scope.

Also I would suggest to make the directive configurable to accept a URL as parameter along with other param like id ,collection ..etc . So you can reuse the same .

And as for the modal you can inject the modal service in directive itself

```
angular.module('directives', [])
.directive('datepicker', ['$timeout','modalService', function ($timeout,modalService) {
    // Runs during compile
    return {
        scope: { ........
        .............
        .............


Gobtn.click(function () {
                .............
                 ..............

                //Call modal service here...
                 modalService.showModel(); // just an sample...call replace with you modal implementation please
            });
        ..............
```

---

And in case if you want to **communicate data with parent controller** you can use [$emit(myEvent, args);](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit) from the directive ....

And then catch the emit message in your controller like this ...

```
angular.module('eventExample', [])
  .controller('EventController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.count = 0;
      $scope.$on('MyEvent',  function(event, args) {
         var anyThing = args.any;
          // do what you want to do
         });
  }]);
```

Also you can add specific scopes to which you want to listen to for an emit or broadcast event using targetScope and currentScope.. refer [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)